# `using` directive for nested namespaces, but require naming the inner namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

Suppose I have a pair of nested namespaces like these:

```
namespace A
{
   namespace B
   {
      int foo = 0;
   }
}
```

If `B` was a class, I could write `using A::B` to avoid typing `A::` every time. I attempted to do the same thing with `B` as a namespace, but the compiler informed me that this was not allowed.

If I were to write `using namespace A::B`, this would introuduce everything *contained* in `B` into the local namespace. I could write `using namespace A`, which would produce the desired results (writing `B::foo`), but this would come with everything else in `A`.

Is it possible to bring `B` into the local namespace without everything else in `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a different syntax, a [namespace alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias):

```
namespace B = A::B;
```